# Swift 4: Firebase Crashed: FIRAScreenViewReporter

Tags: swift, firebase, crash, swift4, crashlytics

I've been receiving this crash log on Crashlytics for almost a month and I still can't figure out what is the problem.

Can anyone help me with this?

> ## 0. Crashed: FIRAScreenViewReporter 0  libdispatch.dylib              0x183370bfc _dispatch_sync_wait + 600 1  Farley
>
> 0x100312424 -[FIRAScreenViewReporter screenParameters] + 4333757476 2 
>   Farley                         0x100312424 -[FIRAScreenViewReporter
>   screenParameters] + 4333757476 3  Farley
>   0x100306bac +[FIRAnalytics
>   logEventWithOrigin:isPublicEvent:name:parameters:] + 4333710252 4 
>   Farley                         0x100306a78 +[FIRAnalytics
>   logInternalEventWithOrigin:name:parameters:] + 4333709944 5  Farley
>   0x100304f6c -[FIRASessionReporter logUserEngagementEventWithScreen:] +
>   4333703020 6  Farley                         0x100305200
>   -[FIRASessionReporter handleScreenDidChangeFromScreen:toScreen:] + 4333703680 7  Farley                         0x100313294
>   -[FIRAScreenViewReporter postScreenDidChangeNotificationWithPreviousScreen:newScreen:] +
>   4333761172 8  Farley                         0x100313014
>   **51-[FIRAScreenViewReporter setCurrentViewController:]_block_invoke + 4333760532 9  libdispatch.dylib              0x183362a14
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16 10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18336b618 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56 11
>   Farley                         0x100312cac -[FIRAScreenViewReporter
>   setCurrentViewController:] + 4333759660 12 Farley
>
>   0x100312840 -[FIRAScreenViewReporter viewControllerDidAppear:] +
>   4333758528 13 Farley                         0x100313e2c
>   -[UIViewController(FIRAScreenClassName) fira_viewDidAppear:] + 4333764140 14 UIKit                          0x18cf885d0
>   -[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:] + 96 15 UIKit                          0x18cee0670 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 852
>   16 UIKit                          0x18cee0bdc -[UIViewController
>   _endAppearanceTransition:] + 228 17 UIKit                          0x18d21054c -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 840 18
>   UIKit                          0x18d3f59b4
>   -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 44 19 UIKit                          0x18d214428
>   __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 188 20 UIKit
>
>   0x18cfd8910 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:]
>   + 116 21 UIKit                          0x18cfd8700 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 252 22 UIKit
>
>   0x18cfd8198 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1128 23
>   UIKit                          0x18cfd7d1c -[UITransitionView
>   _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 120 24 UIKit                          0x18ceffbb4 -[UIViewAnimationState
>   sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312 25 UIKit
>
>   0x18ceff8c0 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 296
>   26 UIKit                          0x18ceff960 -[UIViewAnimationState
>   animationDidStop:finished:] + 456 27 QuartzCore
>
>   0x187a38e14 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 284 28
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x183362a14 _dispatch_client_callout +
>   16 29 libdispatch.dylib              0x18336f698
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016 30 CoreFoundation                 0x18398e544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 12 31
>   CoreFoundation                 0x18398c120 __CFRunLoopRun + 2012 32
>   CoreFoundation                 0x1838abe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
>   33 GraphicsServices               0x185758f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 34
>   UIKit                          0x18cf2b67c UIApplicationMain + 236 35
>   Farley                         0x1001bd99c main (FilterMode.swift:21)
>   36 libdyld.dylib                  0x1833c856c start + 4
>
> --
>
> ## 0. Crashed: FIRAScreenViewReporter 0  libdispatch.dylib              0x183370bfc _dispatch_sync_wait + 600 1  Farley
>
> 0x100312424 -[FIRAScreenViewReporter screenParameters] + 4333757476 2 
>   Farley                         0x100312424 -[FIRAScreenViewReporter
>   screenParameters] + 4333757476 3  Farley
>   0x100306bac +[FIRAnalytics
>   logEventWithOrigin:isPublicEvent:name:parameters:] + 4333710252 4 
>   Farley                         0x100306a78 +[FIRAnalytics
>   logInternalEventWithOrigin:name:parameters:] + 4333709944 5  Farley
>   0x100304f6c -[FIRASessionReporter logUserEngagementEventWithScreen:] +
>   4333703020 6  Farley                         0x100305200
>   -[FIRASessionReporter handleScreenDidChangeFromScreen:toScreen:] + 4333703680 7  Farley                         0x100313294
>   -[FIRAScreenViewReporter postScreenDidChangeNotificationWithPreviousScreen:newScreen:] +
>   4333761172 8  Farley                         0x100313014
>   **51-[FIRAScreenViewReporter setCurrentViewController:]_block_invoke + 4333760532 9  libdispatch.dylib              0x183362a14
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16 10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18336b618 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56 11
>   Farley                         0x100312cac -[FIRAScreenViewReporter
>   setCurrentViewController:] + 4333759660 12 Farley
>
>   0x100312840 -[FIRAScreenViewReporter viewControllerDidAppear:] +
>   4333758528 13 Farley                         0x100313e2c
>   -[UIViewController(FIRAScreenClassName) fira_viewDidAppear:] + 4333764140 14 UIKit                          0x18cf885d0
>   -[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:] + 96 15 UIKit                          0x18cee0670 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 852
>   16 UIKit                          0x18cee0bdc -[UIViewController
>   _endAppearanceTransition:] + 228 17 UIKit                          0x18d21054c -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 840 18
>   UIKit                          0x18d3f59b4
>   -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 44 19 UIKit                          0x18d214428
>   __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 188 20 UIKit
>
>   0x18cfd8910 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:]
>   + 116 21 UIKit                          0x18cfd8700 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 252 22 UIKit
>
>   0x18cfd8198 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1128 23
>   UIKit                          0x18cfd7d1c -[UITransitionView
>   _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 120 24 UIKit                          0x18ceffbb4 -[UIViewAnimationState
>   sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312 25 UIKit
>
>   0x18ceff8c0 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 296
>   26 UIKit                          0x18ceff960 -[UIViewAnimationState
>   animationDidStop:finished:] + 456 27 QuartzCore
>
>   0x187a38e14 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 284 28
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x183362a14 _dispatch_client_callout +
>   16 29 libdispatch.dylib              0x18336f698
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016 30 CoreFoundation                 0x18398e544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 12 31
>   CoreFoundation                 0x18398c120 __CFRunLoopRun + 2012 32
>   CoreFoundation                 0x1838abe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
>   33 GraphicsServices               0x185758f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 34
>   UIKit                          0x18cf2b67c UIApplicationMain + 236 35
>   Farley                         0x1001bd99c main (FilterMode.swift:21)
>   36 libdyld.dylib                  0x1833c856c start + 4

Comment: Is the app itself crashing? Have you stepped through the code to narrow down where/when the crash is occurring?

Comment: I guess so, in Crashlytics it showed Fatal Issue, should be a crash. I've have no idea where to look for the problem